# ¿Existe alguna reminiscencia en el español actual de la confusión "u/v" de la Edad Media?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, historia

Hasta el siglo XVI el idioma español aún tenía la confusión entre las letras *u* y *v*. Véase como ejemplo el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, que usa *u/v/V* indistintamente:

> V. Esta letra V, aunque es vocal, muchas vezes se conuierte en consonãte, y otras pierde la fuerça de letra, quãdo se sigue despues de la q o la g.

De hecho muchas veces no me aparece una palabra que busco en el diccionario de Covarrubias sencillamente porque no la he escrito como se esperaba (ejemplo: para buscar la definición de "tu" hay que buscar "tv"). Así, encontramos palabras como *Guadalquiui*, *estuuo*, *vnos*, *vieja*...

Sin embargo, el *Diccionario de Autoridades* ya distingue entre ambas. Sobre la *u* dice que se escribe, "para diferenciarla de la consonante, más abierta por arriba, y redonda por abajo".

Estaba preguntándome si esta confusión se ha mantenido de alguna forma en alguna palabra, abreviatura, sigla, lo que sea, en el español actual. En un principio pensé en la abreviatura de *usted*, que se acepta que sea *vd*, aunque no lo tengo claro porque hay quien afirma que la *v* procede de cuando se decía *vusted*, y a fin de cuentas la *V* en el siglo XVII era abreviatura de *vuestra* (como en *V.M. = Vuestra Merced*).

Así pues, ¿existe hoy día alguna reminiscencia de la confusión *u/v* de la Edad Media?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estoy nada seguro, probablemente algún experto me va a corregir, pero veo que en numerosos documentos antiguos (no sé si medievales) se escribe **cibdad** y **civdad** lo que actualmente escribimos **ciudad**.

Dado que en el origen está la palabra latina **civis**, y considerando que la confusión de cibdad/civdad es consonántica, supongo que nuestra actual vocal *u* pudo surgir de -o al menos apoyarse en- la confusión ortográfica u/v.

Comment: Muy interesante, de hecho muchos derivados de la palabra van con _v_: _cívico, civilizar, civilización_...

Answer (score 4):

Entiendo que te refieres a algún caso en el que escribamos V y pronunciemos U, o viceversa.

En la [lista de abreviaturas del DPD](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas) aparecen algunos ejemplos que creo podemos considerar válidos para lo que preguntas:

- **V**., **V**d.: **u**sted
- **V**ds.: **u**stedes
- **V**. I.: **u**sía ilustrísima

Los considero válidos precisamente porque, viniendo esa V de "Vuestra", son el mejor ejemplo de algo que era una V y se ha confundido con una U.

En cuanto a palabras completas, casi todas parecen ser variaciones del mismo error: ***u***cé, **u**ced, **u**sarcé, **u**sarced, así como ***u***sted y derivadas, vienen todas de «**v**uestra merced»; ***u***sía, **u**señoría, **u**siría vienen de «**v**uestra señoría» o, más probablemente, de la incorrecta lectura de «**V**. Señoría» como "**u** señoría"; ***u***cencia de «**v**uestra excelencia»; y ***u***sencia de «**v**uestra reverencia».

Se puede argumentar que no son confusiones sino evoluciones normales de la pronunciación de estas palabras, que de por sí incluían una U tras la V inicial; pero opino que en el mantener la V donde se pronunciaba una U es donde radica y se revela la confusión (más descarada si cabe en el caso de las abreviaturas, o en el de *useñoría*).

Por lo demás, tras cerca de 300 años teniendo clara la diferencia entre U y V (en grafía y pronunciación), es normal que sea difícil encontrar alguna palabra aparte de las anteriores *donde la confusión venga del español de la Edad Media*.
Sí que podríamos encontrar, seguramente, palabras importadas de otros idiomas, que en español se escriban con U aunque en su idioma original se escriban con V; pero esa búsqueda correspondería a otra pregunta :D

Comment: El caso de *usted/ustedes* ya lo ha comentado Charlie en la pregunta. En cuanto a *V. I.*, más bien me parece un paralelismo con *V. E.*; al fin y al cabo, si en tercera persona decimos *su excelencia* y *su ilustrísima*, ¿por qué no va a corresponder *vuestra excelencia* con *vuestra ilustrísima*? Pero bueno, son especulaciones.

Comment: He seguido tu enlace y he leído lo que allí pone; pero creo que en este caso el redactor de la RAE ha buscado un compromiso entre *usía* y *su ilustrísima*, que son las dos expresiones que sí he oído utilizar para este caso.

Comment: Sería bueno ver este tema en discusión: Paso de B a U: ¿evolución fonética o falta de ortografía? https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25982/paso-de-b-a-u-evoluci%c3%b3n-fon%c3%a9tica-o-falta-de-ortograf%c3%ada

Comment: @walen no, nada en concreto, simplemente la relación que hay entre los dos temas, perdona, no vi que era la misma persona haciendo las dos preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que buscas parejas de palabras como *meva/meua, teva/teua, seva/seua* en catalán/valenciano, pero no creo que hayan ejemplos así en el castellano.

Lo más cerca en que puedo pensar son palabras así, que no tienen dos formas por una confusión de pronunciar a una ortografía ambigua, sino han sufrido un cambio de sonido natural, y por lo tanto, la ortografía ha cambiado. Algunos de estos sí tienen formas cognadas que consirven este sonido (nota: unos son dobletes cultos prestados del latín):

**p → w**

- capitālem > cabdal > caudal (capital)
- baptistam > ... > bautista (baptista)

**b → w**

- dēbitam > [debda](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BttTijX) > deuda (debido)
- absentis > ausente > ausentismo (absentismo)

**b → w → Ø**

- dubitāre > [dubdar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EDikZAl) > dudar (dubio)
- cubitum > cobdo > codo