# Paso de B a U: ¿evolución fonética o falta de ortografía?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, pronunciación, betacismo

A raíz de la pregunta [¿Existe alguna reminiscencia en el español actual de la confusión "u/v" de la Edad Media?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25965) y de [esta su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25971/13628), me ha surgido una duda.

Tomemos dos ejemplos de evolución de palabras:

- Evolución de "ciudad": lat. *CI**V**ITATEM* → s. IX [CI**V**ITATE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=civitate&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → s. XII [CI**B**ITATE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=cibitat*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → s. XII [CI**B**DAT](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=cibdat&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) / [CI**B**DAD](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=cibdad&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → s. XV [CI**V**DAD](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=civdad&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → hoy CI**U**DAD
- Evolución de "ausencia": lat. *A**B**SENTIA* → s. XIII [A**B**SENTIA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=absentia&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=1500&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → s. XIII [A**B**SENCIA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=absencia&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → s. XV [A**V**SENCIA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=avsencia&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) → hoy A**U**SENCIA

Da la sensación de que, allá por el s. XIII, la pronunciación de estas palabras era con el sonido /b/. Y ya sabemos que [B y V se pronunciaban igual ya entonces](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/446/historical-pronunciation-of-letters-b-and-v): /b/.

Consultando el DLE para [ciudad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9NXUyRH), por ejemplo, lo único que dice es que viene de *civitas*. En ocasiones he visto explicar la evolución *civitas* → ciudad basándose en que en latín (y esto es cierto) se pronunciaba con U: *kiuitas*; pero **la existencia de esas formas con B me hace pensar que la evolución de estas palabras** (desde CIVITAS a CIUDAD, o desde ABSENTIA a AUSENCIA; seguro que hay más) **no viene dada por razones fonéticas sino por una cadena de errores**:

1. Primero, **error ortográfico al escribir V en lugar de B**. Nótese que, en ambos casos, *la forma con B es anterior y mucho más extendida que la forma con V*; no puedo más que pensar que las escasas ocurrencias de las arcaicas formas con V eran simples faltas de ortografía.
2. Posteriormente, **error de confundir V con U** (harto repetido a lo largo de la historia del español, y que da pie a la pregunta arriba enlazada). Recordemos que *la letra U se inventó para diferenciar la "V vocal" de la "V consonante"*, escribiendo la primera más abierta y redondeada. Este cambio tardó siglos en asentarse y es frecuente encontrar en textos antiguos palabras que usan U donde debería poner V y V donde debería poner U. Con tal confusión, no es de extrañar que palabras escritas con V consonante se leyesen a veces como si fuese una V vocal, es decir una U.

¿Es esto correcto? ¿Se da en más casos?

Comment: A priori me resultaría muy, muy extraño que una confusión ortográfica provocase un cambio fonético, siendo que uno aprende a hablar antes que a leer (y en la Edad Media la mayoría ni siquiera aprendía a leer). Me pongo a investigar...

Comment: He encontrado un pdf donde se hace referencia a la evolución de *cibdad* a *ciudad* y lo achaca a la vocalización de /b/ que cambió los hábitos lingüísticos, aquí lo dejo para que le eches un vistazo: https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/35/TH_35_003_062_0.pdf

Comment: También he encontrado la palabra [cabdal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6PGcmDc) que se transformó en *caudal* supongo que de forma similar.

Comment: Lo que dices es posible, aunque no parece ser el caso, ya que como dijo @blonfu, lo que ocurrió fue una vocalización de /b/, que ya venía abriéndose (de oclusiva a fricativa) desde hacía mucho. No es que la gente empezó a pronunciar "mal", es que venía pronunciando cada vez "peor" desde hacía siglos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

En primer lugar no es estrictamente correcto decir que "B y V se pronuncian /b/". Las letras "B" y "V" se pronuncian iguales y formalmente se corresponden con el [fonema](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonema) /b/, pero la realización fonética de dicho fonema es variable y de hecho casi nunca es [b], ni lo ha sido históricamente.

Volviendo hacia atrás ahora... En latín había originalmente un sonido escrito "V" que representaba la vocal /u/ en sus dos realizaciones fonéticas, [u] y [w] (es decir, una /u/ semivocálica en diptongo). Más tarde un cambio fonético hizo que se transformara en dos fonemas diferentes. Vale decir, una palabra que fonémicamente era /kui/ era ambigua ya que podía tener un diptongo ascendente [kwi] o uno descendente [kuj] (dejando de lado que en la escritura, en este caso particular, se utilizaba "QV" para [kw], con lo cual era posible distinguir "QVI" y "CVI").

El nuevo fonema /w/ era extraño al sistema y en algunos contextos su pronunciación evolucionó a [fricativa bilabial sonora](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_bilabial_sonora), [β], emparejándose con /f/ (que muy posiblemente fuera también [bilabial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_bilabial_sorda), [ɸ]). Los sonidos suelen hacer estas cosas; rara vez se encuentran sonidos "sueltos" con características únicas en un sistema fonético.

Por otro lado había en latín una /b/ escrita "B", que con el correr del tiempo empezó a debilitarse entre (y generalmente luego de) vocales y a pronunciarse como fricativa [β]. Ésta fue la primera iteración de un proceso de lenición que después volvió a repetirse en romance (actuando sobre la /b/ producto de la lenición de /p/) al norte de la [línea La Spezia-Rímini](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_Massa-Senigallia).

La confusión frecuente entre "B" y "V" en latín aparece documentada por primera vez en el *Appendix Probi*, una obra del siglo III o IV E.C. que advierte sobre errores comunes en la escritura.

Esta confusión continuó en romance y es la que aparece en los ejemplos antiguos. No había nadie que estandarizara la ortografía y cada cual escribía como mejor podía. Por otra parte se trata de vacilaciones lógicas, puesto que de hecho **no había dos sonidos diferentes** que distinguir, sino uno solo. El escriba podía intentar recordar si en latín ese sonido bilabial provenía de /b/ o de /w/, pero si no tenía cómo saberlo, iba y escribía "B" o "V" según su parecer.

En ciertas posiciones /b/ y /w/ no se confundieron (básicamente en inicio de palabra y luego de nasal) y allí el escriba la tendría más fácil. Eventualmente /w/ fue /v/ en casi todas las lenguas romances, pero en castellano las fricativas sonoras se esfumaron y el contraste se perdió también allí. Desde ese momento sólo quedó un sonido, que representamos /b/ porque es la elección más obvia, aunque como ya se dijo antes, muchas veces no se pronuncia [b].

Hacia el fin de la Edad Media, algunas consonantes que cerraban sílaba comenzaron a ser eliminadas, y la /b/ = [β] que se encontraba en la coda de palabras como *absencia* o *cibdad* se abrió más todavía y se transformó en una /u/ en diptongo, es decir [w]: *ausencia*, *ciudad*. Es decir: ¡recorrió de vuelta hacia atrás el camino de la /u/ semivocálica latina!

Naturalmente esta /u/ se escribió como "V", igual que las otras úes, y siguió escribiéndose "V" en castellano hasta que se introdujo la "U" como letra separada.

[image: Confusión B-V]

Habría que verificar si hubo de hecho una época en que los escribas castellanos prefirieron usar "B" en vez de "V" para transcribir el sonido /b/ en ciertas posiciones incondicionalmente, sea que fuera etimológicamente correcto (como en *absencia*) o no (como en *cibdad*). Es posible que así sea y es posible que haya sido una moda y nada más. En todo caso, no es muy plausible que la ortografía influyese en la pronunciación. Aprendemos a hablar antes que a leer y en el siglo XII o XIII la inmensa mayoría de la gente ni siquiera aprendía a leer.

P.S.: Añado para aclarar fundamentadas dudas del O.P.

El cambio fonético sólo se explica a posteriori. Hay varias teorías sobre por qué un sonido cambia en otro pero en realidad no tenemos ninguna certeza. A veces se habla de tendencias, y una tendencia recurrente en la historia del romance es la preferencia por las sílabas abiertas (es decir, terminadas en vocal). Así vemos cómo las consonantes que cerraban sílaba en latín tienden a perderse en romance, empezando por las de final de palabra. Esta tendencia choca repetidamente contra otro cambio que ocurre al mismo tiempo en cierto período, que es la síncopa o elisión de las vocales no acentuadas. En la evolución de CIVITATIS [kiwi'ta:tis] a *ciudad* encontramos ambas cosas: se pierde la S final, se sincopa la segunda I, la I final primero se abre y luego (en castellano) se pierde, mientras las dos T se debilitan en D: [kiwi'ta:tis] > [tsiβi'tati] > [tsiβ'dade] (más o menos). Esa [β] = /b/ cerrando sílaba "molestaba", como hoy nos "molesta" la /s/ que cierra sílaba a muchos hispanohablantes, desde el Río de la Plata hasta Andalucía. Siendo una fricativa bilabial (o quizá incluso una aproximante), una forma sencilla de "desaparecerla" era transformarla en [w], que está fonéticamente hablando muy cerca y de la cual de hecho había derivado el sonido en cuestión. Así se abría la sílaba haciéndola terminar en un diptongo. Donde la vocal anterior era /o/ o /u/, la /b/ directamente desapareció, de ahí *codo* < *cobdo* < latín "CUBITUM" por ejemplo.

Digo más arriba que preferir "B" en vez de "V" quizá haya sido una moda. Lo cierto es que estamos aquí hablando de un par de palabras y para investigar esto habría que investigar concienzudamente la frecuencia de una y otra en un corpus grande a lo largo del tiempo. Según [leo](https://ebuah.uah.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/10017/7272/Normalizaci%C3%B3n%20Castellano.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), puede haber ocurrido que al escribir consistentemente *cibdad* (en un documento aparece incluso *cipdad*) se intentase remarcar la pronunciación más antigua y conservadora (otro ejemplo es *capdiello* por *caudiello*, hoy *caudillo*). Esto evidentemente no funcionó y finalmente la ortografía se adecuó a la pronunciación real. Y de nuevo: esto puede haber ocurrido en un determinado ámbito (por ejemplo, la corte toledana) y no en otros. Hay que tener en cuenta que hasta el siglo XIII (bajo Fernando III y Alfonso X) no se había decantado ninguna norma de escritura, y no habría una propuesta de ortografía coherente hasta Nebrija (s. XV).

Comment: Entre barras // es fonémico, entre corchetes [] es fonético. El sonido es /b/, con realizaciones [b], [p] o [β].

Comment: Por qué se produce un cambio en realidad nadie lo sabe. Hay alguna especulación en el documento que menciona @blonfu. Al castellano en general no le van las sílabas cerradas y eso le viene desde hace rato. Respondo el resto en una edición.

Comment: @aprente001 hago rollback de tu edición porque la frase no se entiende añadiendo ese **con**

Comment: Sólo un comentario, quizás podrían entenderse mejor los procesos de cambio si se recordara que el castellano de una zona a otra difería bastante, por el aislamiento de algunas, por el sustrato en otras, como ejemplo extremo, en catalán las terminadas en aba se escriben ava, doy este ejemplo no porque sea del castellano obviamente, sino para recordarles acerca del continuum romance, que siglos atrás era mucho más evidente.

Comment: @AndrésChandía No tengo tan en claro los detalles como para eso, pero por otro lado, imagina que se complicaría todavía más el asunto. Por supuesto todo el tiempo estamos hablando del castellano sin mencionar que es simplemente la forma normalizada del dialecto que triunfó.

Comment: @pablodf76 justamente, triunfó luego de unos cuantos siglos, entonces se asentaron por ejemplo el uso de la v y b; pero está en discusión el periodo en que eso y otras cosas no se habían asentado aún, por ello creo que es fundamental tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: Por si sirve de algo, aún hoy en ciertas regiones se percibe un verdadero "flujo" entre una /b/ que se vuelve aproximante y una /u/ semivocal. Ej. en Chile el grupo bu+vocal suele confundirse con gu+vocal y hu+vocal (todos [w]). De ahí la grafía [_guaso_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Jlk2fOS) por huaso y las menos reconocidas pero coloquialmente más populares weno, güevo, etc.

Comment: Gracias por la recompensa, @fedorqui.

Comment: ¡A ti Pablo por la inmensa calidad de tus respuestas!